# How to fix Menu Bar in Responsive Design

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, menu, responsive-design

My menu bar is behaving oddly in IE and Firefox but appears normal and as designed in Google Chrome

The URL is http://bit.ly/1waPylP

How can I fix the menu bar block to get the last menu item -- Contact Us -- to appear in the menu block?

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Elements inside the ul tag don't fit in one row. Try decreasing the Width of each li item. you can do this by decreasing padding-right or padding-left of li tags:

custom-styles.css line 63:

```
div#headercontainer header#masthead div nav#site-navigation div.menu-main-menu-container ul#menu-main-menu li.menu-item{
    background-image: url("../images/Dividing-line-menu.png");
    background-position: right top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 74px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding: 20px 33px 20px 24px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Salar -- I fixed this issue.